# SOAP sessions with javax.xml.soap?

Tags: java, soap

I'm working with a SOAP application in Java.  A new API was added to the server that wants login credentials and returns a guid which is used in queries to the server.  Unfortunately, the sample code was in Perl and I'm having trouble translating it to java:

```
my $client = SOAP::Lite->service("$URL/webservices.php?wsdl")->newSession("$USER", "$PASSWORD"); 
my $result = SOAP::Lite->service("$URL/webservices.php?wsdl")->getMyData($client->{'guid'});
```

I can barely read the Perl here, but I take it there's some sort of "newSession" protocol to SOAP that returns some sort of client object that contains a guid token.

Is there an equivalent to newSession in javax.xml.soap?  I'm working with a pre-existing application, so switching to a different SOAP client api would not be easy.

Comment: From the perl code it looks like `newSession()` and `getMyData()` are two service methods exported in the wsdl.

Comment: Hmmmm; I thought that newSessions was an extension to the SOAP protocol, but now I think I was wrong.  Let me play with it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was my misunderstanding; thank you.

Comment: Matt b, if you'll make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.